# Get db query times for Mongo with Mongoid/Moped?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, activesupport

Ok so I have a rails app that uses mongo as the db and mongoid/moped. I was attempting to use to the active support notifications to get the db_runtime so i could graph the information compared to view render times.

I have been trying a few ways but have had no luck. I am also new to the active support/notifications stuff.

Currently I am trying to use this https://gist.github.com/tomafro/829710, I can't seem to get a value in the mongo_runtime key in the payload hash. It is always 0 and the console always shows (Mongo: 0, Mongoid: 0)

The gist code is being stored in a file in **config/initializers/**

I have also tried the same guys gem and it produces the same results.

If there is a better way to get the query times for a call I am more then willing to switch. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at [rack-mini-profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) this is *Middleware that displays speed badge for every html page. Designed to work both in production and in development.* 
 there is a rails cast video that shows step my step how to set up [368-miniprofiler](http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler)

Comment: Didn't exactly solve the question but it appears short term it can be used. Never really messed around with Rack so I am guessing that on each page load I can grab this timing info a store it if I wanted outside of it's logging